# Looking for a way to map all my weekend driving

Tags: maps

I love driving to cities around me and going to new places. I'm interested in computer software or device that I can use to track all my driving. The idea is to record or have a history of the roads I have taken before..  I would prefer an offline solution but if you know any iOS app that I can use for this purpose, please let me know.

Comment: I have a bicycle app that does this kind of recording, quite usual in those. But I have never met an app or navigator that does it for car travel.

Comment: Google maps can track all your movements, if you switch it on - check under 'timeline'. That can help you

Comment: This belongs on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/